Impossible to do processing by iteration in the model designer since QGIS 3.38
I was working on 3.36 (on Windows), and I have a model designer with iterate activate on a input Vector Feature. It was working prefectly.
Now I use the 3.38 version but when I lauch my Model Designer, I don't have error, but my treatment stop after the first feature.
Is this a known regression? I haven't found any information about it.
Normally my treatment produce a result layer for each feature (when I activate iteration).
But now I have just one result (the first feature).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Add more information about the model, so it is possible to reproduce the problem.
